# Capture template parameter of variadic templated arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following (incomplete, not-working) definition:

```
template<typename T, std::function<Args(Context&)>... Funcs>
struct constructor
{
    T construct(Context& ctx)
    {
        return T(Funcs(ctx)...);
    }
};
```

What I want is a templated class - the first argument is the constructed type and all following are functions to be called, the user templates with `std::function`s that are then called to produce the values for the constructor of type `T`.

I don't see a possibility to make this code work, let beside capturing the return types of the functions. I want the user to use it like this:

```
std::function<int(Context&)> ind = [](Context&) {return 2;};
Constructor<int, ind> c;
// c.construct(...) returns 2 by calling the constructor int(int) with argument
//                      ind(ctx) - which returns 2.
```

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you want. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I added a bit of information, maybe that makes it more clear

Comment: Yes, but your `construct` is probably meant to use `return`.

Comment: Why not take the arguments through the constructor?

Comment: What is `Context&`?  Can you describe the problem that led you to this proposed solution?  Returning `2` is easy, your code is not legal, having a description of the actual problem you need to solve will help people generate a solution to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be roughly what you're looking for. Keep in mind that a `std::function` can't be a template parameter.

```
template <typename R> using Generator = std::function<R (Context&)>;

template <typename T, typename Generators, std::size_t... Is>
T constructImpl(Context& ctx, const Generators& generators,
                std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return T(std::get<Is>(generators)(ctx)...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
class Constructor {
   std::tuple<Generator<Args>...> generators;

public:
   Constructor(Generator<Args>... generators)
       : generators(std::move(generators)...)
   {}

   T construct(Context& ctx) {
       return constructImpl<T>(ctx, generators,
                               std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
   }
};
```

Usage:

```
Constructor<int, int> c([](Context&) { return 2; });
int i = c.construct(context);
assert(i == 2);
```

Comment: Could we also implement a `make_Constructor` so that `auto c = make_Constructor<int>([](Context&) { return 2; });` works, requiring fewer explicit template arguments?

Comment: Yes, by taking the functions as template arguments and using `decltype` or `std::result_of` to determine their return type.

Answer (score 1):

Types cannot depend on run time data.

Calling `std::function<X(Y)>` requires run time data.  So your type cannot depend on `std::function<X(Y)>`, so the type cannot be used as a template parameter.

Now, it can depend on a pointer to a global object: that is interestingly enough not run time state as far as C++ is concerned.

As such, your design is fundamentally flawed.

If you want a function such that it returns 2, this works:

```
template<class...ignored>
struct Constructor {
  template<class... also_ignored>
  Constructor(also_ignored&&...) {}
  template<class... also_ignored>
  int construct(also_ignored&&...) { return 2; }
};
```

this will pass the unit tests described in your OP, with the exception that you cannot pass `ind` to `Constructor` as it is not legal.  However, dropping it from the type signature doesn't matter.

If you want more power, we could do this:

```
template<class T, class... Functors>
struct Constructor {

  T construct( Context& ctx ) {
    return T( Functors{}( ctx )... );
  }
};
```

in this case you need stateless function objects:

```
struct ind { int operator()(Context&)const{return 2;} };
```

much like how `std::map` requires stateless comparison objects.

If your function objects require state, then you need to store a copy of them for `Constructor` to access (possibly within `Constructor`), and you might need the tuple and indexes trick to store them.  ("indexes trick" is a helpful google)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying WHY it doesn't work. The last bits are a bit ... strange. I clearly state that the user should hand over functions which are then used to create objects that are then used to create the final value. I don't quite get what the point of your example is, examples are chosen to be simple, in this case I have one functions (that happens to always return 2) to create an int that is passed to the constructor of int. Tell me where you got lost so I can provide a better example next time.

Comment: @worldsender I asked some questions as a comment to your original question.  You have a `...` and `Context` undefined in your code.  They may be related.  What `Context` is, and how you intend to use it, might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Construct` can just be a function:

```
template <typename T, typename... Funcs>
T construct(Context& ctx, Funcs... funcs) {
    return T(funcs(ctx)...);
}
```

Whose usage could be in your example could be:

```
int x = construct<int>(ctx, [](Context& ) { return 2; });
```